# Defining expected values for fields in SOAP java webservices

Tags: java, web-services

I have created a webservice using Java, Spring, CXF. The webservice returns POJO which has been annotated with XmlRootElement(name = "LeaveRecord"). This POJO has fields and the getters are annotated with @XmlAttribute. Is there a way to define (through annotation I expect?) what values can be expected for this field (eg. the status field may return APPROVED, PENDING or DECLINED) and I would hope these expected values would pull through to the WSDL when it gets created so that clients wanting to use this webservice could know beforehand what values to expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider coding those expected values as Enums. That way you have total control over values of those fields:

```
public Enum ExpectedValues {
    APPROVED,
    PENDING,
    DECLINED
}
```